# Как сделать генерацию в зависимости от нажатой кнопки?

Tags: веб-программирование

уже очень долго ищу ответ на вопрос. Необходимо реализовать на сайте взаимосвязанный выбор создания ссылки.
В итоге это должно выглядеть подобным образом: https://xiaomi-centre-service.ru/uslugi/smartfonyi/
Суть этой панели в том, что конечная страница, куда перейдет браузер, будет зависеть от того, какие кнопки пользователь нажал.
Сначала он может выбрать поломку, затем устройство, а может сначала выбрать устройство, а только затем подняться выше и выбрать поломку, каким-то образом ссылки подменяются.
Пробовал делать это на табах, но клиенту не понравилось, потому что порядок выбора односторонний.
Спасибо большое за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Если уберёте ссылку, которая со временем можете умереть, и добавите пояснение в сам ответ, то вероятность получить ответ возрастёт.

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса. По ссылке указанного функционала нет. Но по описанию можно было бы даже на ajax  c привлечением backend такое зарядить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня это реализовано примерно так

```js
const filters = {}
// Добавляем кнопкам data атрибуты (data-filter, data-value)

// Вешает событие onclick на все кнопки
document.querySelectorAll('button[data-filter]').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const key = btn.getAttribute('data-filter')
    const value = btn.getAttribute('data-value')
    filters[key] = value
  })
}) // P.s можно добавить проверки на наличие атрибутов

// И код для получения querystring
const getQueryString = () => Object.keys(filters).map((key) => {
  return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(filters[key])
}).join('&')
```

```html
<button data-filter="a" data-value="1">Параметр a = 1</button>
<button data-filter="b" data-value="2">Параметр b = 2</button>
<button data-filter="c" data-value="3">Параметр c = 3</button>
<button onclick="alert(`${window.location.origin}/?${getQueryString()}`);">Получить querystring</button>
```